# how to read email attachment using microsoft graph api with delegate permissions in C# Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am new to Microsoft Graph API. My requirement is to read all emails attachment and insert them into SQL Database. My client is allowing only delegate permission to implement this requirement. I follow the below-mentioned code but it is neither showing me any error or any result.

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_appid";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var inboxMessages = await graphClient
                    .Users["tinywang@xx.onmicrosoft.com"]
                    .MailFolders["inbox"]
                    .Messages
                    .Request()
                    .Expand("attachments")
                    .Top(20)
                    .GetAsync();
```

Anyone, please help me to resolve this issue. Microsoft is going to disable Basic Authentication by end of this month, so I have to implement this before that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if no error or result, what's the response data you are getting? are you sure you have attachments in your test emails?

Comment: Yes, it has an attachment. But above not giving me anything. I think it is not hitting the API.

Comment: I want to implement this code example provided by Microsoft. Can you tell me, what will be the authProvider here? 
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var attachments = await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Attachments
 .Request()
 .GetAsync();

Comment: You need to use **Interactive** flows like authorization code instead of client credentials for `Delegated` permissions. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider)

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I ran the same code as you and got same results without **output** or **error** like below:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_appid";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var inboxMessages = await graphClient
                    .Users["admin@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"]
                    .MailFolders["inbox"]
                    .Messages
                    .Request()
                    .Expand("attachments")
                    .Top(20)
                    .GetAsync();
```

**Response:**

[image]

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to use interactive flow like **authorization code** for `Delegated` permissions.

I got the results successfully via **Graph Explorer** that use `Delegated` permissions like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<messageID>?$expand=attachments
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can get the **sample** C# snippet here:

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var message = await graphClient.Me.Messages["messageID"]
.Request()
.Expand("attachments")
.GetAsync();
```

[image]

**Complete Sample Code:**

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_appid";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var authorizationCode = "code that you got in below request";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.authorizationcodecredential
var authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, authorizationCode, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);

var message = await graphClient.Me.Messages["messageID"]
    .Request()
    .Expand("attachments")
    .GetAsync();
```

To get the authorization **`code`** value, you can use below request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran the above request in browser. I got **`code`** along with **redirect URI** like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But my problem is not yet resolved. I am unable to get the Authorization code using httpClient.GetAsync and I am passing all these parameters https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: not getting any errors debugging the httpClient object, it is showing no result found. Everything working fine on Graph explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in a different way. So I am posting my code so it may help someone.

```
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var userNameCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(mailboxUser, mailboxPass, tenantId, clientId, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(userNameCredential, scopes);
var graphResult = graphClient.Users[mailboxUser].MailFolders["inbox"]
                        .Messages
                        .Request()
                        .Expand("attachments").GetAsync().Result;

var attachmentMessage = graphResult.Where(x => x.HasAttachments == true);
foreach (var message in attachmentMessage)
{
    var mailReceiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(message.ReceivedDateTime.ToString());
   string fromEmail = message.From.EmailAddress.Address.ToString();
  string mailSubject = message.Subject;

 if (attachment.ODataType == "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment")
  {
    var attachmentRequest = graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages[message.Id]
                          .Attachments[attachment.Id]
                          .Request()
                          .Expand("microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item")
                          .GetAsync();

     var itemAttachment = (ItemAttachment)attachmentRequest.Result;
     var itemMessage = (Message)itemAttachment.Item;
   }
 }
```

This is the solution I have implemented.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**